# Mongodb aggregation pipeline project

Tags: mongodb, project, pipeline, lookup, aggregation

Good day all,

i need some help in getting an aggregation pipeline to work, been trying to get it working for some time but getting only half way.
this is my setup

**Users** document is as follow:

```
{
    "_id": { "$oid": "5fea4f976ca46d93c010d33d" },
    .....................
    "firstname": "firstname1",
    "lastname": "lastname1",
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": "value4",
    ..................
    "certifications": {
        certs: [
            {
                "_id": "5fea44b96ca46d93c010d330",
                "itemID": 1,
                "date_certified": "2011-05-30 05:09:48"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5fea44b96ca46d93c010d334",
                "itemID": 3,
                "date_certified": "2007-01-30 06:01:51"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5fea44b96ca46d93c010d337",
                "itemID": 5,
                "date_certified": "2007-09-21 16:52:52"
            }
        ]
    },
    .......................
    ...................
    .....................
},

{
    "_id": { "$oid": "5fea4f976ca46d93c010545453" },
    .....................
    .....................
    "firstname": "firstname2",
    "lastname": "lastname2",
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": "value4",
    ..................
    "certifications": {
        certs: [
            {
                "_id": "5fea44b96ca46d93c010d330",
                "itemID": 2,
                "date_certified": "2011-05-30 05:09:48"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5fea44b96ca46d93c010d334",
                "itemID": 4,
                "date_certified": "2007-01-30 06:01:51"
            }
        ]
    },
    .......................
    ...................
    .....................
}
```

**Certifications** document is a follow

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fea44b96ca46d93c010d32e"
  },
  "itemID": 1,
  "acronym": "acro1",
  "country": "my Great Country",
  "name": {
    "key1": "My Key 1 description",
    "key2": "My Key 2 description",
    "key3": "My Key 3 description",
    "key4": "My Key 4 description"
  },
  "website": "www.myGreatWebsite.com"
},

{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fea44b96ca46d93c010d32f"
  },
  "itemID": 2,
  "acronym": "acro2",
  "country": "my Great Country",
  "name": {
    "key1": "My Key 1 description",
    "key2": "My Key 2 description",
    "key3": "My Key 3 description",
    "key4": "My Key 4 description"
  },
  "website": "www.myGreatWebsite.com"
},

{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fea44b96ca46d93c010d330"
  },
  "itemID": 3,
  "country": "my Great Country",
  "name": {
    "key1": "My Key 1 description",
    "key2": "My Key 2 description",
    "key3": "My Key 3 description",
    "key4": "My Key 4 description"
  },
  "website": "www.myGreatWebsite.com"
},

{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fea44b96ca46d93c010d331"
  },
  "itemID": 4,
  "country": "my Great Country",
  "name": {
    "key1": "My Key 1 description",
    "key2": "My Key 2 description",
    "key3": "My Key 3 description",
    "key4": "My Key 4 description"
  },
  "website": "www.myGreatWebsite.com"
},

{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fea44b96ca46d93c010d332"
  },
  "itemID": 5,
  "country": "my Great Country",
  "name": {
    "key1": "My Key 1 description",
    "key2": "My Key 2 description",
    "key3": "My Key 3 description",
    "key4": "My Key 4 description"
  },
  "website": "www.myGreatWebsite.com"
}]
```

now my aggregation

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'certifications', 
      'let': {
        'certs': '$certifications.certs'
      }, 
      'pipeline': [
        {
          '$match': {
            '$expr': {
              '$in': [
                '$itemID', '$$certs.itemID'
              ]
            }
          }
        }, {
          '$project': {
            '_id': 0, 
            'itemID': '$itemID', 
            'description': '$name.key1', 
            'acronyme': '$acronym', 
            'country': '$country', 
            'count': {
              '$size': '$$certs'
            }, 
            'date_cert': '$$certs.date_certified'
          }
        }
      ], 
      'as': 'certifications'
    }
  }
])
```

and the result is

```
{
  .........
  ...........
  "firstname": "firstname1",
  "lastname": "lastname1",
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3",
  "key4": "value4",
  ..................
  certification: {
    certs: [
      {
        itemID: 1,
        country: 'my Great Country',
        description: 'My Key 1 description',
        count: 1,
        date_cert: [
          0:"2005-01-06 10:48:16"
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
  ........
  .........
},

{
  .........
  ...........
  "firstname": "firstname2",
  "lastname": "lastname2",
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3",
  "key4": "value4",
  ..................
  certification: {
    certs: [
      {
        itemID: 2,
        country: 'my Great Country',
        description: 'My Key 2 description',
        count: 2,
        date_cert: [
          "2005-01-06 10:48:16"
          "2014-06-21 22:44:56"
        ]
      },
      {
        itemID: 4,
        country: 'my Great Country',
        description: 'My Key 4 description',
        count: 2,
        date_cert: [
          "2005-01-06 10:48:16"
          "2014-06-21 22:44:56"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  ........
  .........
}
```

but the expected result is

```
{
  .........
  ...........
  "firstname": "firstname1",
  "lastname": "lastname1",
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3",
  "key4": "value4",
  ..................
  certification: {
    certs: [
      {
        itemID: 1,
        country: 'my Great Country',
        description: 'My Key 1 description',
        date_cert: "2005-01-06 10:48:16"
      },
    ],
    count: 1,
  }
  ........
  .........
},

{
  .........
  ...........
  "firstname": "firstname2",
  "lastname": "lastname2",
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3",
  "key4": "value4",
  ..................
  certification: {
    certs: [
      {
        itemID: 2,
        country: 'my Great Country',
        description: 'My Key 2 description',
        date_cert: "2005-01-06 10:48:16"
      },
      {
        itemID: 4,
        country: 'my Great Country'
        description: 'My Key 4 description',
        date_cert: "2014-06-21 22:44:56"
      }
    ],
    count: 2
  }
  ........
  .........
}
```

basically i'm looking to merge the result of the pipeline match stage with the documents of the certifications lookup, so that i can use both.
any pointers would be greatly appreciated in formulation the aggregation.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$unwind` deconstruct `certs` array
- `$lookup` with `certifications` pass `certifications.certs.itemID` as localField and `itemID` as foreignField and result as `certification`
- `$unwind` deconstruct result from lookup and in `certification`
- `$group` by `_id` and reconstruct `certs` array and push your required fields after merging using `$mergeObjects`, get count using `$sum`

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$certifications.certs" },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "certifications",
      localField: "certifications.certs.itemID",
      foreignField: "itemID",
      as: "certification"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$certification" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      certs: {
        $push: {
          $mergeObjects: [
            "$certifications.certs",
            {
              country: "$certification.country",
              description: "$certification.name.key1"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D31GO7cy8ph)

---

Second approach without $unwind and $group, this may cause performance and speed issues,

- `$lookup` with `certifications` collection
- `$map` to iterate loop of `certifications.certs` array
- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `certification`, check condition of `itemID` and it will return specific field,
- back to `$map`, merge current object and return object from `$reduce` using `$mergeObjects`
- get count of `certs` using $size`

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "certifications",
      localField: "certifications.certs.itemID",
      foreignField: "itemID",
      as: "certification"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "certification": "$$REMOVE",
      "certifications.certs": {
        $map: {
          input: "$certifications.certs",
          as: "c",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$c",
              {
                $reduce: {
                  input: "$certification",
                  initialValue: {},
                  in: {
                    $cond: [
                      { $eq: ["$$this.itemID", "$$c.itemID"] },
                      {
                        country: "$$this.country",
                        description: "$$this.name.key1"
                      },
                      "$$value"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "certifications.count": { $size: "$certifications.certs" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rVG76HaGKSm)

Comment: thank you but how do i correctly add the date field to the lookup result. now it is adding all the dates as an array to each certifications and not the corresponding date to each.

Comment: I have updated the answer you can review.

Comment: thank you that is were i was heading after some google research, however in my user document i have like 15 or more other fields, is it possible to add them also without having to manually re-write all of them. the reason is that if i add a field to the model i do not want to have to fo and modify the aggregation also.

Comment: you can use $mergeObjects, i have updated answer.

Comment: thank you again for the quick response, maybe i'm getting this wrong but from your update it looks like the "mergeObjects" will be done at the certifications field. What i want is to get all other fields from the parent User object. i have update the User document and the results so you can get a better idea of what i'm looking for. I need to get all the keys of the User document back with the updated "Certifications" filed from the lookup. Sorry if i did not explain it well.

Comment: okay no there is not straight way to do this in $group stage, you need to specify the name of all keys like `{ key1: { $first: "$key1" } }` so on for other keys.  i will try without $unwind and $group but might be it will slow in big database,  i will update you soon if it is possible without $unwind and $group.

Comment: @boulepick i have updated second approach without $unwind and $group, review it.

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what i was looking for. it works great.